# Running Dlookup() on a query with row count column as criteria (MS access)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Im trying to run Dlookup to return all values of a column in a query's results. As Dlookup can only return 1 result I have added a row count column to the query so I can use the row count as the criteria for the Dlookup.

My query results look like this in the results
[Query design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCXPP.png)
[Query results 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNXb2.png)

In SQL view the query is as follows:

```
SELECT tblAssets.SerialNumber, tblAssets.ID, tblAssets.AssetType, tblPlacing.Location, tblPlacing.PlacingStartDate, tblPlacing.PlacingEndDate, RowNumber([ID]) AS [NO]
FROM tblAssets INNER JOIN (tblLocations RIGHT JOIN tblPlacing ON tblLocations.LocationID = tblPlacing.Location) ON tblAssets.ID = tblPlacing.AssetID
GROUP BY tblAssets.SerialNumber, tblAssets.ID, tblAssets.AssetType, tblPlacing.Location, tblPlacing.PlacingStartDate, tblPlacing.PlacingEndDate, RowNumber([ID])
HAVING (((tblAssets.AssetType)=55) AND ((tblPlacing.Location)=[Forms]![FrmPPM]![TXTLocationID]) AND ((tblPlacing.PlacingEndDate) Is Null) AND ((ResetRowNumber())<>False));
```

I have added the row count with the following video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWbpzETe-M0), let me know if more information about this is needed.

The query results look to be correct, however, when using the Dlookup (beneath) it returns null.

```
Dim VAR1 as Variant     
VAR1 = DLookup("[SerialNumber]", "QRYPPM", "[NO] = 1")
```

When I try and return the [NO] column value it works.

```
VAR1 = DLookup("[NO]", "QRYPPM", "[SerialNumber] = '6501038'")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your data, so can't run a full test, but I ran something similar using my `RowNumber` function (below), and `DLookup` was able to filter on the returned rownumber (your [NO]) and return a value from another field.

So, try to use this function (your SQL will need minor adjustments, see in-line comments, please):

```vb
' Builds consecutive row numbers in a select, append, or create query
' with the option of a initial automatic reset.
' Optionally, a grouping key can be passed to reset the row count
' for every group key.
'
' Usage (typical select query having an ID with an index):
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RowNumber(CStr([ID])) <> RowNumber("","",True));
'
' Usage (typical select query having an ID without an index):
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RowNumber("","",True)=0);
'
' Usage (with group key):
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID]), CStr[GroupID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RowNumber(CStr([ID])) <> RowNumber("","",True));
'
' The Where statement resets the counter when the query is run
' and is needed for browsing a select query.
'
' Usage (typical append query, manual reset):
' 1. Reset counter manually:
'   Call RowNumber(vbNullString, True)
' 2. Run query:
'   INSERT INTO TempTable ( [RowID] )
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable;
'
' Usage (typical append query, automatic reset):
'   INSERT INTO TempTable ( [RowID] )
'   SELECT RowNumber(CStr([ID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM SomeTable
'   WHERE (RowNumber("","",True)=0);
'
' 2020-05-29. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RowNumber( _
    ByVal Key As String, _
    Optional ByVal GroupKey As String, _
    Optional ByVal Reset As Boolean) _
    As Long
    
    ' Uncommon character string to assemble GroupKey and Key as a compound key.
    Const KeySeparator      As String = "¤§¤"
    ' Expected error codes to accept.
    Const CannotAddKey      As Long = 457
    Const CannotRemoveKey   As Long = 5
  
    Static Keys             As New Collection
    Static GroupKeys        As New Collection

    Dim Count               As Long
    Dim CompoundKey         As String
    
    On Error GoTo Err_RowNumber
    
    If Reset = True Then
        ' Erase the collection of keys and group key counts.
        Set Keys = Nothing
        Set GroupKeys = Nothing
    Else
        ' Create a compound key to uniquely identify GroupKey and its Key.
        ' Note: If GroupKey is not used, only one element will be added.
        CompoundKey = GroupKey & KeySeparator & Key
        Count = Keys(CompoundKey)
        
        If Count = 0 Then
            ' This record has not been enumerated.
            '
            ' Will either fail if the group key is new, leaving Count as zero,
            ' or retrieve the count of already enumerated records with this group key.
            Count = GroupKeys(GroupKey) + 1
            If Count > 0 Then
                ' The group key has been recorded.
                ' Remove it to allow it to be recreated holding the new count.
                GroupKeys.Remove (GroupKey)
            Else
                ' This record is the first having this group key.
                ' Thus, the count is 1.
                Count = 1
            End If
            ' (Re)create the group key item with the value of the count of keys.
            GroupKeys.Add Count, GroupKey
        End If

        ' Add the key and its enumeration.
        ' This will be:
        '   Using no group key: Relative to the full recordset.
        '   Using a group key:  Relative to the group key.
        ' Will fail if the key already has been created.
        Keys.Add Count, CompoundKey
    End If
    
    ' Return the key value as this is the row counter.
    RowNumber = Count
  
Exit_RowNumber:
    Exit Function
    
Err_RowNumber:
    Select Case Err
        Case CannotAddKey
            ' Key is present, thus cannot be added again.
            Resume Next
        Case CannotRemoveKey
            ' GroupKey is not present, thus cannot be removed.
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            ' Some other error. Ignore.
            Resume Exit_RowNumber
    End Select

End Function
```

The full story can be found in my project [VBA.RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers).

Comment: Thanks @Gustav, your function worked well and worked in the Dlookup. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Gustav, RowNumber keeps on changing value with is neither going up sequentially or starting at 0. Im using this "<>RowNumber("","",True)".

I am able to get the correct counted numbers with GroupRowNumbers however, I am unable to get a value from Dlookup.

The RowNumber did work correctly for a time but without changing the Query it has stopped working.

Comment: Something must have changed. Perhaps reset manually: `Call RowNumber(vbNullString, True)`.

Comment: Hi @Gustav, That isn't working. Could it be something to do with the rownumber(key, groupkey, reset)? I just have it as ("","",True) at the moment.

FYI Ive already done the obvious such as restart/ compact and repair.

Comment: Have in mind, please, that I have neither your data nor your code, and _isn't working_ doesn't tell much. A similar test works here, so double-check your implementation. The only trap (which may require a manual reset) is, that the function cashes the data, thus sometimes returns data where it shouldn't, but never no data.